# Weird inconsistency between df.drop() and df.idxmin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am encountering a weird issue with pandas. After some careful debugging I have found the problem, but I would like a fix, and an explanation as to why this is happening.

I have a dataframe which consists of a list of cities with some distances. I have to iteratively find a city which is closest to some "Seed" city (details are not too important here).

To locate the "closest" city to my seed city, i use:

```
id_new_point = df["Time from seed"].idxmin(skipna=True)
```

Then, I want to remove the city I just found from the dataframe, for which I use:

```
df.drop(index=emte_df.index[id_new_point], inplace=True)
```

Now comes the strange part; I've connected the pycharm debugger and closely observed my dataframe as I stepped through my loops.

When you delete a row in pandas with `df.drop`, it seems deletes the entire row *by row number*. This means for example that if I delete row #126, the "Index column" of the dataframe doesn't adapt accordingly. (See screenshot below)

[image]

`idxmin` seems to return the *actual* index of the row, so the index associated with the row in the pandas data-frame.

Now here comes the issue: Say I want to remove row 130 (EMTE WIJCHEN). I would use `df.idxmin` which would give me the *index*, namely 130. Then i call `df.drop[index]`, but since df.drop uses *row numbers to delete instead of dataframe indices* and I just deleted a row (#126) it now (wrongly) removes row #131 which slided up into place 130.

Why is this happening, and how can I improve my code so I can drop the right rows in my dataframe? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated (Also if there's a better practice for approaching these kinds of problems, maybe a solution which doesn't adapt the dataframe in place?)

Comment: you could use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` after drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas don't update the index column because it is not always a range of numbers, it can be, for example, names (John, Maria, etc) and thus it wouldn't make sense to "update" the index after dropping a specific row. You can reset_index after each iteration like this:

```
df.drop(index=emte_df.index[id_new_point], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```