# Pandas returning data in a weird format (Int64, Float64)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with pandas, and I need the index of some row where some value is Max. To do this I use `seed_row = df[df["veghel_time"] == df.veghel_time.max()]` To get the row where the column `df["veghel_time"]` has the maximum value (details not important).

When I use `print(seed_row_df.index)`, instead of a regular index value (in this case 126) I get:

`Int64Index([126], dtype='int64')`

Similarly, `print(seed_row_df["veghel_time"])` gives me

```
126    119
Name: veghel_time, dtype: int64
```

Instead of simply the value of the column, which is `119`.

Finally,    `print(seed_row_df["Lat"])`
gives:

```
126    6.57619
Name: Long, dtype: float64
```

Instead of simply `6.57619`

Why is this, and what are the implications of this? Say I want to use these values (For instance sum them). Will this lead to problems? Is there a way to tell pandas that I simply want the values and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a single row of a dataframe.

You can use `.squeeze()` on it (or other types) to get the plain value out if you need it for something non-pandas.

Comment: Is this simply the way pandas represents its data? You say "If you need it for something non-pandas". Do you imply by that, that I can simply use this "data representation" that pandas uses so to speak, for panda related functions? Or maybe even numpy functions/sklearn functions? Since np and pandas are closely related, and sklearn mostly works with np-like structures (ndarrays). And what is the benefit of pandas representing data this way? Sorry for all the questions just wanna get to the bottom of this =) If you're busy any resources on the topic are also appreciated

Comment: It's a slice of a dataframe with one column and one row. You can use `.to_numpy()` to get a numpy array from a dataframe (`df.to_numpy()`) or series (`df.col.to_numpy()`).

Comment: Ahh. I see. Starts to make sense now. Thx =)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your result is a tuple represented by the index and value of the data type – perhaps because of some cyclical backend in pandas. A simpler approach would be to query the index of the max value directly:

```py
# gets the index of max time
seed_row_idx = df.veghel_time.idxmax()

# get the value of some column at that index
my_value = df.iloc[seed_row_idx, "Lat"]
```

Comment: I know about idxmax() but I need the entire row instead of just the id of that row, doing it like this is more robust because you lose the ability to find indices (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960083/weird-inconsistency-between-df-drop-and-df-idxmin which I posted yesterday)

Comment: In that case @Psychotechnopath – I'd suggest using `df.iloc[seed_row_idx,:]`

Comment: Thx for response, appreciate it =). 

Yes but the problem is that iloc and drop (AFAIK, or maybe I'm mistaken) use *row numbers* and not indices to drop/locate... Thus modifying your df inplace disaligns the indices and the row numbers, leading to weird errors (Again referring to my other Question here). Would love to learn if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: In that case @Psychotechnopath -- use `df.loc[seed_row_idx, :]`

Comment: So, df.loc[] for label-based indexing, df.iloc[] for row-based indexing? What about dropping? Is there a label-based equivalent of df.drop?

Comment: Correct. And by default, `df.drop()` will drop by row index name